# Why manually deployment on Heroku dashboard didn't "rake db:migrate" automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I didn't use Heroku for a while. I found Heroku change something so want to give it another try.

But after I click the "Deploy Branch" button, my app is still not working.

So I check the build log and realize Heroku seems not do the db:migrate command.

But it did do the asset:compile command. And I don't found anywhere to click to do the db:migrate thing.

So I have to do it with command line tools, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well known limitation of Heroku. It won't run your migrations out of the box. However, you can automate it in couple of ways:

1. You can write a simple script that will first push new code to Heroku git repository and then run migrations. The problem is that you need to run this script locally on your machine
2. You can add [this buildpack](https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-rake-deploy-tasks) and then set environmental variable `DEPLOY_TASKS` to `db:migrate`. You can do this via UI, command line `heroku config:set DEPLOY_TASKS='db:migrate'` or you can add everything to `app.json` so it should work out of the box with deploy button.
3. You can use [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) by adding `release: rake db:migrate` to your `Procfile`.

Please keep in mind that there are many issues related to migrating your database during deployment. You can read about it in the docs for release phase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.